# Why does Gmail send email from my server to spam?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

Gmail sends email originating from my server to spam. I have only sent email to myself. rDNS is setup, SSL encryption is setup. Gmail says:

> It contains content that's typically used in spam messages.

This is email header:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of apache@host.domainname.com designates IPHERE as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=apache@host.domainname.com
Return-Path: <apache@host.domainname.com>
Received: from host.domainname.com (domainname.com. [IPHERE])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v40si1865929otd.212.2017.05.27.09.31.43
        for <emailaddr@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 27 May 2017 09:31:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of apache@host.domainname.com designates IPHERE as permitted sender) client-ip=IPHERE;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of apache@host.domainname.com designates IPHERE as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=apache@host.domainname.com
Received: from host.domainname.com (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by host.domainname.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4499DAA01A4 for <emailaddr@gmail.com>; Sat, 27 May 2017 18:31:25 +0200 (CEST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at host.domainname.com
Received: from host.domainname.com ([127.0.0.1]) by host.domainname.com (host.domainname.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id DKDJPupZmSLo for <emailaddr@gmail.com>; Sat, 27 May 2017 18:31:24 +0200 (CEST)
Received: by host.domainname.com (Postfix, from userid 48) id D0998AA01BA; Sat, 27 May 2017 18:31:24 +0200 (CEST)
To: emailaddr@gmail.com
Subject: Test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:sendMail.php
From: webmaster@domainname.com
Message-Id: <20170527163124.D0998AA01BA@host.domainname.com>
Date: Sat, 27 May 2017 18:31:24 +0200 (CEST)
```

This is message:

> Yes it is.

Any idea what could be the issue? Are there any general guidelines?

Comment: This is probably a better question for [webmasters.se].

Comment: ...or perhaps [so].

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the spam classification is due to a number if things, including:

1. No reputation from sender IP.
2. Use of php script (which can imply hacked website) - see X-PHP+Originating-Script header. Similarly with "apache" &"webmaster" in sender details.
3. Small body size.